# cordova android sdk 27 - icons can't be added to the app

Tags: cordova, android-sdk-tools

In previous sdk's  I was able to add icons just by copying res folder with icons to the platforms/android folder and rebuilding the android app.
New android sdk (27) works otherwise, and after 
    cordova platforms android add
creates another android folder hierarchy than before. After moving res folder with the icons and trying to rebuild android app it has a lot of errors of missing Manifest file and more.

```
(node:31800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Visual Studio Projects\manageApp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at Object.parseElementtreeSync (D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Visual Studio Projects\manageApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\util\xml-helpers.js:180:27)
    at new AndroidManifest (D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Visual Studio Projects\manageApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidManifest.js:29:20)
    at updateProjectAccordingTo (D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Visual Studio Projects\manageApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:187:20)
    at D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Visual Studio Projects\manageApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:47:16
    at _fulfilled (D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Visual Studio Projects\manageApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Visual Studio Projects\manageApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Visual Studio Projects\manageApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Visual Studio Projects\manageApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:570:49
(node:31800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:31800) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Adding manifest file just causes another errors trying to recreate old code files hierarchy that was created by old sdk(26)

**So the question is, how to change app icons with new android sdk?**

Comment: which android version did you add?

Comment: I added Android P (API 27)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
The path of res folder and manifest changed from the platform/android to the platform/android/app/source/main. After I uploaded my icon pics there everything worked